# Right Substring Statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I want to substring the seventh and eighth caractere from string by starting on the right

I want to make dynamic this try :

```
select substring(right(P.Name,8), 1,2)
```

How do you properly write a Right Substring function SQL? What I am doing is not working.

Comment: Can you define "not working"??? some sample data and expected output would help greatly.

Comment: This work if the string has 8 caractere or more ,

Comment: Step 1 - decide what you want returned if the string has less than 8 characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should look how to properly use `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('123456789',7,2)
```

The `7` is the position where you start, and the `2` is the length of the string that you want to retrieve.

**EDIT**

If you want `SUBSTRING` starting from the right (according to your comments), you can use `REVERSE`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REVERSE('123456789'),7,2)
```

Comment: Yes i know , but i want do somthing by starting on right

Comment: @stoner what does that means?, you wanted the 7th and eighth character from your string

Answer (score 3):

This makes more sense to me than the double `REVERSE()` method:

```
select substring(P.Name,len(P.Name) + 1 - 8, 2)
```

We use length + 1 because `substring()` is a 1-based rather than 0-based function.  That is, the first character is character 1, not character 0.

Note that if the field is less than 7 characters long, an empty string is returned.  If the field is exactly 7 characters long, only the 7th character is returned.  If the field is at least 8 characters long, the 7th and 8th characters are returned.